# Нейросети и хранение параметров

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Для каждых входных данных весы ставятся по разному, и эти веса нужно где то хранить. Но когда нейросеть кормят миллионами данных, то для каждых данных надо свой уникальный вес (если данные не одинаковы).

Вопрос, где эти веса хранятся? Ведь если их хранить в файле, то файл будет весить несколько гб, и пока система их откроет пройдёт немало времени.

Comment: немного не так - для каждого набора входных данных уникальные веса конфигурация нейросети

Answer (score 2):

Смысл нейросети (как и вообще любой модели машинного обучения) не в том, чтобы просто запомнить все данные один в один, а чтобы найти в них какие-то закономерности, какую-то общность разных данных. Поэтому нейросеть всегда меньше размером, чем данные, на которых её учат. Иной раз очень сильно меньше, на порядки. И хранят "снимок" модели (и веса и конфигурацию нейросети тоже) в файле, да, почему бы и нет.
В том, что модель будет долго читаться с диска, проблем никаких нет. Обучаться и дообучаться большая нейросеть может много дней, по сравнению с этим чтение её снимка с диска - это ерунда по времени.
А при использовании натренированных нейросетей для предсказания их во-первых заранее стараются упростить, "сжать", а во-вторых обычно для этого делают сервис, который подгружает один раз натренированную нейросеть в память и дальше уже все предсказания производятся нейросетью, находящейся уже в памяти, на каждое предсказание нейросеть с диска не читают, это очень неэффективно и вообще бессмысленно.